# Passing ServiceLayer's services to WCF service

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, dependency-injection, wcf

I want to expose my business logic via WCF service in the intranet environment. I have N-tier architecture, pretty simple:

**Database** -> **.Data** (DAL) -> **.Business** (Service Layer) -> **WCF**

So, far I have 4 services in `Service Layer`, but only one WCF service. I here comes the problem. My WCF service uses all 4 services. I'm using Dependency Injection, so technically I should add those 4 services into WCF constructor. I already has parameter for `IMapper`, `ILogger` and `DbContextFactory`.

I was thinking of creating a ServiceFactory and passing it to the WCF service. So then, WCF Service can create whatever service it needs.

But I'm not sure if this is an antipattern or not? What do you suggest?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If your proposed change doesn't solve a problem, you don't need it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem I have is that it's getting smelly. I got rid of `IMapper` and `DbContextFactory` since they are injected into Services themselves and are not needed in WCF service, but it's still 5 parameters. So I have an idea, to create a factory for Services. I'm not sure if this is a good practice though - it sounds like *Service Locator anti-pattern*, doesn't it?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't done a cost-benefit analysis.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what does it mean? Do you have any advice? My second idea, was to create many WCF services , one per service from the `Service Layer`.

Comment: Forget about code smell for a moment.  What's the simplest thing that will work?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The simplest way is to leave my WCF Service with 5 parameters: ILogger and 4 services from the Business layer (Service Layer). That works already. It smells only in the class definition, cause Ninject silently inject those parameters (at least that). So that would be the simplest thing that works. I'm worrying about the future, what If I will need more services.

Comment: [Cross that bridge when you get to it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for help, I really appreciate. I will do exactly what you suggested but... Can you answer a theoretical question then "What If I'm on that bridge" and I see new services coming. What would you do? Would you create a ServiceFactory or create more WCF services?

Comment: Which way is the simplest?  Which way provides the most benefits with the least cost?  These are the questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure if I agree with you. Sometimes the simplest way isn't the best. It may look good, but if fact it introduces an anti pattern and lots of issues in the future. Like breaking "SOLID" patterns, coupling the code etc...That's where you need experience to see those "traps" and that's why I'm here. From what I've read from your answers it looks like both solutions are not that bad. Both have the same cost and same benefits imho.

Comment: First, make sure you understand clearly what "best" means.  Breaking SOLID isn't the problem; it's the *consequences* of breaking SOLID that are the problem, and if there are no consequences, or the benefits of breaking one of the SOLID principles outweigh the drawbacks, then you should happily break SOLID.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid business logic in the WCF project.

If your WCF project uses more than one Service Layer project then it must(?) have some business logic in it.

Either: Make a new WCF 'hosting layer' project for each Service Layer project

Or: Make a new Service Layer project which encapsulates the others and the business logic which links them

Comment: Thanks Ewan, By "WCF project" or service I mean the whole class with `[ServiceBehavior]` decorator. I inject 4 different service from `Service Layer` *(btw. I hate that naming, it should be called Logic/Business layer, so it's not confused with web services)*. Anyway, it doesn't mean that there is business logic. There's none. I use one service per WCF method. WCF is just a proxy between the client and `Service Layer`. So I started thinking.. hm.. maybe I should create more WCF `[ServiceBehavior]` services (with different contracts). Hm.. interesting, Can services in `Service Layer` be nested?

Comment: then you are hosting multiple services in one hosting project? split it

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm gonna refactor at some point. I'm not sure yet how. When you have a `Car` and a bunch of methods like "GetCarById", "GetCarOwner", "GetCarsOnSale", "GetAllCars"... where should methods like "GetAllCarTypes" or "GetCarBrands" go? It's not part of the Car. Types are like "Cabro, Sedan... etc" Is it a part of the Car aggregate root?